# Placed on 24 hour shift under National Minimum Wage (UK)

Tags: salary, united-kingdom, health, law

A friend of mine works in a care home for young adults with severe learning difficulties. These people need 24-hour care.

She is paid approximately £7 per hour. She has today been placed on a rota for the following shifts:

14:15 - 21:45 followed by 21:45 - 07:15 followed by 07:15 - 14.45

She is concerned about working over 24 hours in a row (the overnight shift 21:45 to 07:15 is a shift where she is in the workplace allowed to sleep, but can be woken at any time to help the patients).

She is concerned that this will have a negative impact on her own health (if she is woken, she will get no sleep) and also on the quality of care that she can give to the patients.

Furthermore, for the overnight shift (21:45 to 07:15) she is paid a lump sum of £30 which is £3.15 an hour - she is entitled to a National Minimum Wage of £5.55 per hour.

Exactly which laws and regulations are being breached here so that she can effectively raise the issue to her boss?

Comment: You need to talk to your local Citizens Advice Bureau, a qualified lawyer or a union rep rather than the Internet. But before all that, what happened when your friend raised this issue with their boss?

Comment: She raised the issue with her boss mentioning that she did not feel comfortable working a full 24+ hours with no break and was told "that's just the way it's done here".

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like that middle shift is more being "on call on site" than working. The expectation is that she will sleep all night. Once in a while she will be woken. She gets paid a small amount to be on call, and -- over time -- the amount she actually is awake and working in a week of such shifts should be quite small.

If that's how this plays out - once a week or so she is woken, up for an hour, and then can sleep again - it may be a tolerable situation and one for which the compensation is adequate. But if she is woken every night, and has to struggle for hours each night dealing with a patient in crisis, and has no chance to catch that sleep back up again, clearly, that is very different. She'll be exhausted and at great risk of making an error that could harm a patient.

Your local Citizens Advice Bureau can tell you whether "on call on site" shifts are in fact legal or not. Her colleagues can tell her what the on call shifts are truly like. If being woken is rare, and she likes the rest of the job, she may decide to accept having an unpleasant night from time to time. If being woken is the norm, and these back-to-backs are a common sight on the rota, then it would seem, legal or no, that the fit is not good and she would do well to look for a job with a more human schedule.

Comment: She seems to think that the night time shifts are often just made up of sleeping and not being interrupted, but I would have thought that they should prepare for the worst. If she **is** kept awake all night (which she definitely could be if a patient needs to go to hospital, for example) then she will still be expected to do the next shift - with no sleep.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.acas.org.uk/index.aspx?articleid=1373 she has the right to 11 uninterrupted hours of rest in any 24 hour period. Which means 13 hours work, which includes several 20 minute breaks, would be the maximum within any 24 hours period.

Now the minimum wage applies to all of your work - as long as they pay more than the minimum wage times 24 for 24 hours of work that would be fine legally. On the other hand, slavery is illegal in the UK, so I think the correct expression in the UK when asked to work another eight hours for £3.15 an hour is "f*** off". That care home is making a lot of money every week from each young adult living there; they can more than afford to pay decent wages.

Comment: The 11-hour rule affects on-call work like this, because if she is woken during the night, that time-off clock starts again. This means that she is legally unavailable for her following shift, which could (almost certainly *would*) have a knock-on effect on whether she is paid for it. A lawyer is needed here.

Comment: Where do you get that “average trick” regarding the minimum wage? If the minimum wage is *5.55 £ per hour*, then it must be applied *per hour*.